# Literal empty line in pandoc manpage markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, manpage

This markdown manpage:

```
%frobnicator(3)

# NAME
**frobnicator** — frobnicates the frobs

# OPTIONS
  **-a** *a*: the letter a \
  **-b** *b*: the letter b \
  \
  **-c** *c*: the letter c \
```

renders (`pandoc -s --to=man frobnicator.md  |PAGER=cat man -l -`) to:

```
frobnicator(3)                                                  frobnicator(3)



NAME
       frobnicator — frobnicates the frobs

OPTIONS
       -a a: the letter a
       -b b: the letter b
       -c c: the letter c
                                                                frobnicator(3)
```

How do I put an empty line between `-b` and `-c`?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
%frobnicator(3)

# NAME
**frobnicator** — frobnicates the frobs

# OPTIONS

  **-a** *a*: the letter a \
  **-b** *b*: the letter b

  **-c** *c*: the letter c \
```

Edit: my only other idea:

```
%frobnicator(3)

# NAME
**frobnicator** — frobnicates the frobs

# OPTIONS

|  **-a** *a*: the letter a \
|  **-b** *b*: the letter b \
|
|  **-c** *c*: the letter c \
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that's even worse. (It joins the b line and the c line)

Comment: See my edit? That would work with the outputs I'm familiar with (haven't used pandoc for man pages before).

Comment: That's giving me the same output as the original code.